# Extracting JSON value from its parent

Tags: python, json

I am making a request and I want to parse its response:

```
{"hash160":"4b1ddbf92df072c298a0c58043db58b26771f926","address":"17rBT3f4UmnFGrngasBprqXjQQnZVztfDz","n_tx":0,"n_unredeemed":0,"total_received":0,"total_sent":0,"final_balance":0,"txs":[]}
```

I tried to extract values `total_sent` and `final_balance` like this: `print(str(wallet['n_tx']['total_sent']))` and I got a `Type Error: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

How can I extract those values?

Comment: Please provide desired output

Comment: `wallet['n_tx']` is `0`, so `wallet['n_tx']['total_sent']` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print them both out you can try this:

```
[print(str(wallet[i])) for i in ['n_tx', 'total_sent']]
```

The reason you are getting the error is because `wallet['n_tx']` is an integer and therefore has no `total_sent` key.  In order to access both values you need to extract them one at a time.

```
a = wallet['n_tx']
b = wallet['total_sent']
```

Comment: I am very grateful for your quick reply, but that makes no sense with pastebin.com/S8RUr14P

Comment: @LegaLeon  Which part doesn't make sense?  I see your pastebin I don't understand what your issue is?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it was just a blockchain response typo

Answer (score 0):

The code you are including is essentially asking for value indexed by 'total_sent' WITHIN wallet['n_tx'].

If you want 'n_tx' and 'total_sent',

```py
n_tx = wallet['n_tx']
total_sent = wallet['total_sent']
print(n_tx, total_sent)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it makes no sense with https://pastebin.com/S8RUr14P